# Referencing a static file for tests with protractor in typescript

Tags: typescript, protractor, automated-tests, cucumber

I'm writing a test case, where i have to upload a .csv file. 
I'm using protractor, and write my tests in typescipt, with cucumber. 
This is how I define the file i want to upload.

```
let path = require('path');
let remote = require('selenium-webdriver/remote');
let fileToUpload = "invitation_list.csv";
let absolutePath = await path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
```

The error I get is:
WebDriverError: invalid argument: File not found...

I figured out that the problem is that path.resolve tries to find the csv in a e2e-build folder where the javascript files are generated, however obviously, the csv file is not there. 
Can i tell protractor exactly where should he look for the file?
I tried using the full relative path (let fileToUpload = "dir1/dir2/dir3/invitation_list") but it changes nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your protractor configuration, you can define its working directory by adding the key value pair `root: process.cwd()` which you can then use throughout the tests.

protractor.conf.js (e.x it is located at C:/Users/Foo/Tests)

```
params: {
    root: process.cwd(), // C:/Users/Foo/Tests
},
```

Then to use it:

```
import { browser } from 'protractor';

let path = require('path');
let remote = require('selenium-webdriver/remote');
let fileToUpload = "invitation_list.csv";
let absolutePath = await path.resolve(`${browser.params.root}/dir1/dir2/dir3/invitation_list`, fileToUpload);
```